# Setting a DB Session level parameter in EclipseLink for every connection?

Tags: java, eclipselink

I'd like to set a database session variable for every session from Eclipselink. The SQL I want to execute is something like:

```
begin DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER('MyApplicationName'); end;
```

If I try to create a SessionEvent listener that will execute the command I seem to get caught in infinite recursion.

```
myServer.getEventManager().addListener(new SessionEventAdapter() {
    public void postConnect(SessionEvent evt) {
        evt.getSession().executeNonSelectingCall(new SQLCall("begin DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER('MyApplicationName'); end;"));
    }
});
```

Am I going about this the wrong way with the event listener or does the SQL command need to be executed in a special way?

Comment: Can you show us the stacktrace of the StackOverflowError of the infinite recursion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are executing a query on the session while it is still obtaining a connection for some other process.  The connection the postConnect event is triggered for is unavailable to the session until your event finishes - that means any query on the session will be forced to obtain a different connection.

You need to use the accessor within the SessionEvent to obtain the connection and use it to directly execute a JDBC statement.  Something like

```
  public void postConnect(SessionEvent evt) {
    Connection connection = ((Accessor)event.getResult()).getConnection()
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.execute("begin DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER('MyApplicationName'); end;");
  }
```

Comment: I figured that is what was going on, but wasn't sure how to either get the raw connection or if there was a better way to go about it. Thanks for answer.