# How can I set an Oracle role in Eclipselink using Oracle jdbc? DBA's will not grant default role

Tags: oracle, jdbc, eclipselink

There is no Oracle jdbc driver property for Oracle role ('Set role myrole', e.g.). DBAs will not grant the default role privilege to the user, so I must explicitly set the role myself. I do not know how this can be done in Eclipselink.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100698/setting-a-db-session-level-parameter-in-eclipselink-for-every-connection

Answer (score 0):

A non-DBA can't grant the ROLE to himself. So if she refuses to grant the ROLE directly, it is possible to grant it to a `ROLE` you already have granted. See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6012.htm#i2066772) for other possibilities.

Example

**DBA**

```
create role jpa_role;
-- presumably you the CONNECT role granted
grant jpa_role to connect;
```

This *enables* you to set the role; otherwise you get

```
ORA-01924: role 'JPA_ROLE' not granted or does not exist
```

Having said that this is the JDBC way to set the role

```
con.createStatement().execute("set role JPA_ROLE")
```

So you need to get the DB connection and issue the statement above (I use Groovy, Java should be similar syntax).

Maybe there is a more native JPA way how to execute a statement, which others will possible suggest.